# Ionic 1 App on Input fields are not auto scrolling

Tags: ios, angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-directive

I have created few pages with input fields directives in Ionic App Lib v1.3.1.

If page has `<ion-content overflow-scroll="false">` on inserting values on keyboard open that field get scroll up in iOS, but if page has been inserted by `ng-include` like

```
<ion-content overflow-scroll="false">
    <div ng-include src="'sample/sample.html'"></div>
</ion-content>
```

the input fields in that page does not auto scroll when keyboard opens up to input value on iOS but it works well on Android.

Please anyone have any idea how to tell ionic to auto scroll fields in case of iOS.

I also tried `cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(false);` but it gives other scrolling issues on iOS, like if input field is clicked keyboard opens up but focus shifts to combobox which is below the input field and shows combobox data which is wrong behaviour.

Thanks